# Beautiful Soup4 Find All Get a Certain Value Using Indexing

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I recently created a web scraper, and I am scraping a date of a site. HTML snippet below:

```
    <dl class="dl-horizontal"> 
      <dd>
          ::before
              September 22, 1966
          ::after
      </dd>
    </dl>
```

When I do:

`dob = soup.find_all("dd")`

I get (edited to hide some personal info):

`[<dd>Clevenger</dd>, <dd>XXX-XX-XXXX <div class="adtl">You should <a href="https://www.example.com">click here</a> to find out if blah blah.</div></dd>, <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="geo">47.579909, -117.479347</a></dd>, <dd>111-111-1111</dd>, <dd>1</dd>, <dd>September 22, 1966</dd>, <dd>52 years old</dd>, <dd>Virgo</dd>]`

All I want is the date: September 22, 1966

How would I get that?

**Edit:**  Changed find to find_all and xPath:

`//*[@id="details"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/dl[6]/dd[1]`

CSS selector:

`div#details > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > dl:nth-of-type(6) > dd`

Comment: `soup.find()` should return only the first element, are you using `find_all` ?

Comment: We need  a few more html to help you here, the goal is to find a unique selector for this block. CHeck the dev tool in your browser to have an idea (css selector, xpath ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out the class/id name for that (or any piece of attribute really)
It'll be much easier if you could write something like this:

```
dob = soup.select("dd[class=date]")
```

In case you couldn't.. consider Regex to find out which `<dd>` tag contains a date:

```
months = '[(January), (February), (March), (April), (May), (June), (July), (August), (September), (October), (November), (December)]'

for elem in dop:

    text = elem.getText()    
    pattern = str(months) + r'\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}'

    if re.search(pattern, text) != None:
        print('matching!')
    else:
        print('not a match!')
```